Nested If's with Vlookups not working in Excel
I have an MS Excel 365 (with current patches) spreadsheet that tracks mileage and tolls to various locations.  I am trying to build in logic that won't populate mileage and tolls if I have 2 entries to the same location on the same day (as it would be one trip not two).
Today I am using VLookUps to populate the mileage and tolls from a separate sheet in the same workbook.  They work, but don't have the logic to verify if the destination is the same location on the same day.  I have separate VLookUps for Mileage and Tools (as they are separate cells), but I am trying to build this logic into a single formula and have it populate both of the cells.

Spreadsheet details

Where D2 & D3 are dates
Where H2 & H3 are locations
$A$4:$G$210 is a list of locations to search from to match from Column H on the that has Mileage to the locations in column F on the alternate sheet and Tolls in Column G on the alternate sheet.

Both VLOOKUPs work in the cells as stand alone formulas
=VLOOKUP(H3,'Payment info'!$A$4:$G$210,6,0)
=VLOOKUP(H3,'Payment info'!$A$4:$G$210,7,0)
Here is the formula as it stands today (not working):
=IF ($D$2<>$D$3), SetCellValue($R$3,(VLOOKUP(H3,'Payment info'!$A$4:$G$210,6,0)))), (IF(($H$2<>$H$3), SetCellValue($S$3(VLOOKUP(H3,'Payment info'!$A$4:$G$210,7,0)),SetCellValue($R$3,"NOTHING")))
This formula in Cell R4 produces this error message.

It is possible that the values in D2 & D3 (rows 3 & 4) could be the same but the values in H3 & H4 could be different (rows 3 & 4).  In the first case, I want the values from the alternate page to populate R3 & S3, but R4 & S4 to be blank or "--".  in the second case, I want values to be populates in R5 & S5, but not R4 & S4.
If the dates are the same, then I want to compare the values from H3 & H4 (locations) to see if they are the same.  If they are then blank out R4 & S4.  If they are different, then populate R3 & S3 with the values from the VLookUp on the alternate sheet.
Screenshot and mock up of data in Columns R & S.  Note Row 4 being populated with "--" :

This all makes sense to me so if it's not clear, please let me know.

Start by checking your parenthesis. You have closed/ended the IF right after the logical test. Everything that is coming after it is not evaluated and because you have closed the parenthesis, Excel does not understand why there are more parts to your IF. That's why it shows the error message.

Did you use 3rd-party add-in? I can not use "SetCellValue" function on my Excel. But you may try IF($D$2<>$D$3,SetCellValue($R$3,(VLOOKUP(H3,'Payment info'!$A$4:$G$210,6,0))),IF($H$2<>$H$3, SetCellValue($S$3,(VLOOKUP(H3,'Payment info'!$A$4:$G$210,7,0))),SetCellValue($R$3,"NOTHING"))).

@Emily, It looks like it was an older Method that may no longer be supported, but still availavle see this link from {MS}(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2003/aa209005(v=office.11))
I don't have to use it, but I am trying to have a single formula that populates information in 2 adjacent cells.
I just saw Excel can only populate values in cells where the formula exists.  In that case, I need 2 formulas one for column R and one for column S.  Column S could look like: If <> "--", (VLOOKUP(H3,'Payment info'!$A$4:$G$210,7,0))

@ReddyLutonadio, Thank you.  There was a problem with the parenthesis, but based on my having learned that Excel from this Stack Overflow post, my original logic was flawed.
I will be posting the solution that I used to solve the problem shortly.

My original hope to populate information into 2 cells with a formula in a single cell was not able to be done in Excel without using VBA (not how I wanted to solve the problem as it would be overly complex).
What I had to do was add logic into the existing VLookUP formulas so that if had 2 events at the same location on the same day, it would not count the mileage and tolls twice, but if I went to the same location 2 days in a row, it would still populate the mileage and the toll values in the correct cells for the second day only as I go back to the office/home overnight.  I discovered this additional logic was necessary and I used an AND function to set the criteria for the IF.  here are the updated and correct formulas:

Adv Logic MILEAGE (column P)--> =IF(AND(H4=$H5,$D4=$D5),"--",(VLOOKUP($H5,'AltSheetWithMileage&TollInfo'!$A$4:$G$210,6,0)))
Adv Logic Tolls (column Q)--> =IF(AND(H4=$H5,$D4=$D5),"--",(VLOOKUP($H5,'AltSheetWithMileage&TollInfo'!$A$4:$G$210,7,0)))


Thank you to both @ReddyLutonadio & @Emily for their initial help on getting me onto the correct path.
